# Invalid prop `x` of type `string` - expected `object` + 'y' of type `string` - expected `array`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Tried to search for an answer but did not found matching one. I have a problem with my simple React app (contactForm + contacts list). Locally app is not rendering and I got two alerts:

> *"react.js:20478 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `contact` of type `string` supplied to `ContactForm`, expected `object`.
>       in ContactForm (created by App)
>       in App"*

and

> *react.js:20478 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `items` of type `string` supplied to `Contacts`, expected `array`.
>       in Contacts (created by App)
>       in App*

What is interesting, alerts shows **only locally** (I run app with http server). When I upload code on GitHub and run via GitHub Pages (link in repository) - app is rendering and none of alerts occurrs. Can somebody explain this to me?

Files structure - script.js (only rendering App) and components: App, Contact (single contact), Contacts (list of contacts) and ContactForm.

App:

```
var contacts = [
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'Jan',
      lastName: 'Nowak',
      email: 'jan.nowak@example.com',
    }
    ...
  ];

  var contactForm = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: ''
  };

  var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className='app'>
          <ContactForm contact={contactForm}/>
          <Contacts items={contacts}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

Contact:

```
var Contact = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
      item: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className={'contactItem col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'}>
            <div className={'contactImg col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4'}>
                <img className={'contactImage'} src={'http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/gCons/contacts.png'}/>
            </div>
            <div className={'contactItem col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'}>
                <p className={'contactLabel'}>Imię: {this.props.item.firstName}</p>
                <p className={'contactLabel'}>Nazwisko: {this.props.item.lastName}</p>
                <a className={'contactEmail'} href={'mailto:'+this.props.item.email}>{this.props.item.email}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    },
  });
```

Contacts:

```
var Contacts = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
      items: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    },

    render: function() {
      var contacts = this.props.items.map(function(contact) {
          return <Contact item={contact} key={contact.id}/>
      });

      return <ul className={'contactList'}>{contacts}</ul>
    }
  });
```

ContactForm:

```
var ContactForm = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
      contact: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <form className={'contactForm'}>
          <input type={'text'} placeholder={'Imię'} value={this.props.contact.firstName}/>
          <input type={'text'} placeholder={'Nazwisko'} value={this.props.contact.lastName}/>
          <input type={'email'} placeholder={'E-mail'} value={this.props.contact.email}/>
          <button type={'submit'}>Dodaj kontakt</button>
        </form>
        )
    },
  })
```

Link to the full code:
https://github.com/galdranorn/react-exercises

Comment: Please provide the relevant code in the question itself. For further help, see this [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Thanks for your remarks, did as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@galdranon: I checked out your code and am not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: code was OK, but I had cashe issue. Cleaning the browser/ctrl+F5 habit solves the problem.